# 2560x1600 graphics card and 2560x1440 monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, screenresolution

The maximal resolution my graphics cards supports is 2560x1600, however there are no monitors on the market with this resolution, the closest one is 2560x1440.

**What will happen if I connect such a monitor to my PC? Is everything going to look normal?**

Comment: Try it.  Look in your display settings to see if it can accommodate the ratio change.

Comment: Nothing bad will happen.  It will pick a resolution that fits the monitor.

Comment: This likely depends on the software (drivers) included with the card and/or monitor. These could potentially allow the correct resolution (2560x1440), which would likely show things correctly (note that for games, this also assumes a "correct" resolution available in-game).

Answer (score 1):

2560x1600 is a [16:10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16:10_aspect_ratio) aspect ratio (width:height). 16:10 used to be fairly popular for monitors before higher resolutions became more common. In the early 2000's up to about 2008, 16:10 was the way to go. Since then, not so much, except for laptop internal screens.  1920x1200 was a very popular laptop screen resolution, & indeed some laptops still come with 16:10 screens in higher resolutions.

In the meantime, everybody got "HD" TVs & monitors 1920x1080 - television broadcasts are in this resolution & aspect ratio… [16:9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16:9_aspect_ratio)

Everyone else wanted to do the same thing, 16:9 became far more popular for all things screen-related.

Then came higher resolution external monitors to the mainstream… they're all 16:9. the older 16:10 ratio just wasn't popular any more.
So, no-one ever made a modern higher resolution 16:10 monitor.
<sub>Well, there might be some, somewhere, but they're certainly not common</sub>

It's fairly easy to specify 2560x1600 as a maximum resolution for a graphics card, as "maximum" also includes smaller.

2560x1440 is… wait for it… 16:9.

***Everything*** that supports 2560x1600 also supports 2560x1440